# как продлить линию в будущее

Tags: r

Есть у нас какой то вектор

```
vect <- c(1,3,7,4,12,8,14,9,21)
plot(vect,t="l")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выбираем две точки и проводим линию между ними

```
i <- c(3,5)
points(i,vect[i],lwd=2,col=4)
segments(3,vect[3],5,vect[5],col=2,lwd=2,lty=3)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос : как мне продлить эту линию в будущее на n значений
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И получить эту линию в виде вектора с значениями

Comment: Продлить в будущее... вы машину времени делаете?

Comment: @VerNick тоже посмеялся с этого) Зашел на вопрос из-за названия)

Comment: здесь вам не конкурс бестолковых комментариев!

Comment: @mr.T А зачем так вопрос называть?

Comment: @mr.T Вы это имели ввиду? https://cf.ppt-online.org/files/slide/c/c9DKQzvlewSimVHh03yAB2FusO7q4oWZ1CRXf5/slide-6.jpg

Comment: @ValeraGrinenko Видимо, он имел ввиду вот это https://cf.ppt-online.org/files/slide/c/c9DKQzvlewSimVHh03yAB2FusO7q4oWZ1CRXf5/slide-6.jpg XD

Comment: @mr.T Что-то у меня подозрение, что вы себе лайки накручиваете фейковым аккаунтом.

Comment: У меня подозрение что я вас узнал https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8B&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUA785UA785&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=xPBj5ZUk84XAtM%253A%252C-uOlyjHjQD8v9M%252C_&usg=AI4_-kQ4QfSa0iK0gVlzFRjdGAAS2aH7Lw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC_uKsjs3eAhUD2ywKHcJGBnIQ9QEwAHoECAIQBA&biw=1366&bih=631#imgrc=VIwqV5R5GXny2M:

Comment: @mr.T https://www.google.com/search?q=%D1%83+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BC&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjRsOfDns3eAhUhl4sKHYiMDmoQ_AUIDigB&biw=1715&bih=757#imgrc=gBtf_cFEP5EgMM: даже веселее стало

Comment: Линия, исходящая из одной токи в безконечность, называется [луч](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%83%D1%87_(%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Comment: @ nick_n_a спасибо, буду знать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Написал такую функцию

```
fu <- function(vec,x1,x2){
p.ln <- x2-x1+1
my.trend <- approx(vec[c(x1,x2)],n = p.ln)$y
my.trend <- c(rep(NA,x1-1),my.trend) 
fst <- tail(diff(my.trend),1)
future <- cumsum(  c(    tail(my.trend,1) ,  rep(fst,length(vec)-x2)     ))[-1]
res <- c(my.trend,future)
lines(res,t="l",lwd=2)
return(res)
}
```

В принципе работает

```
fu(vect,i[1],i[2])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

только громоздкая получилась((